# Ionic2: Icon inside Menu-Button is cut

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I importet an example app (menu) and added a button with icon & text to the menu:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
      <button ion-item icon-left (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
        Logout
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Sadly, this results in a not fully shown Icon (I test my app in Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you have to use the attribute item-left at ion-icon

```
 <ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
      <button ion-item icon-left (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon item-left name="log-out"></ion-icon>
        Logout
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```